# PHP GET With Empty Variable

Tags: php, get

Hello i am new to PHP and was wondering if you could use the `$_GET` method without the `data=` for example.

```
www.mydomain.co.uk/?dataiwanttoget
```

Instead Of

```
www.mydomain.co.uk/?data=dataiwanttoget
```

Any help would be appreciated im a beginner at PHP, so i am sorry if this does not make much sense.

Comment: impossible, `data` is the key in `$_GET` array

Comment: Its not impossible... It can be done in several ways, eg. by `htaccess`, or by as mentioned by @Marc in his answer.

Comment: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` will contain what you are looking for.

Comment: @Sanchit you are right, sorry I have a long day and isnt thinking very straight :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course. To just get the string after the `?` you can use PHP's [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) function:

```
$value = key($_GET);
```